# Writing a SQL Query using BIGDATA Cititrips

Tags: sql

Hi I am writing this code on SQL. It is giving an error. An anyone please make corrections.

```
SELECT 
  Concat(start_station_name, 'to' ,end_station_name) As route,
  usertype,
  Count(*) as num_trips,
  Round(Avg(cast(tripduration as int64)/60).2) Float64 as duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
Group by 
  start_station_name, 
  end_station_name,
  usertype

Order by 
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I wrote exactly what i learnt in a video lesson on coursera but it isnt working. Can anyone explain.

Comment: Hi - it would be helpful if you updated your question with the actual error message but I can see at least 2 issues 1) the columns in your GROUP BY need to match the non-aggregated columns in your SELECT, and they don’t 2) you seem to have a random “Float64” in your ROUND function

Answer (score 0):

```
Round(Avg(cast(tripduration as int64)/60).2) Float64 as duration`
```

Should be...

```
Round(Avg(cast(tripduration as int64)/60.0),2)         as duration
                                        ^^ ^   ^^^^^^^
```